# Number of positive integral solutions of $x_1*x_2*x_3=30$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Find the number of positive integral solutions of $x_1*x_2*x_3=30$

The prime factors of $30$ are: $2,3,5$. This now we have to put them into 3 groups with any number of elements(even 0 as $x_!,x_2,x_3$ can also be $0$) in each group.

Case 1: all in 1 group=$\frac{3!}{0!0!3!}=1$
Case 2: 2,1,0 elements in groups=$\frac{3!}{0!1!2!}=3$
Case 2: 1,1,1 elements in groups=$\frac{3!}{1!1!1!3!}=1$

But the answer is 27 and I have no clue where I have gone wrong.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I thought it was just integral solutions.

Comment: @ATHARVA Easy to miss.

Comment: $x_1=2 , x_2=3 , x_3=5 $ is different than $x_1=3 , x_2=5 , x_3=2.$

Comment: @ATHARVA ah okay...but that is just 3! times the answer I got, not 27 either

Comment: Pick which $x$-value receives the factor of $2$ (*three choices*).  Pick which $x$-value receives the factor of $3$ (*three choices*).  Pick which $x$-value receives the factor of $5$ (*three choices*).  Applying multiplication principle, there are $3\cdot 3\cdot 3=27$ possibilities.  For more complicated questions with higher exponents on the prime factors, apply stars and bars instead for each prime.

Comment: 2,1,0 can be done many different ways. For instance, $15\cdot2\cdot1$ or $10\cdot3\cdot 1$.

Comment: @Arthur only 3 ways: 15*2*1, 10*3*1, 6*5*1

Comment: @JMoravitz but how is this approach wrong (3!*5)?

Comment: As ATHARVA already pointed out, the problem implies that the order of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ matters.  You seem to be working only with the solutions where $x_1\geq x_2\geq x_3$ while that need not necessarily be the case.

Comment: @JMoravitz So for that we've multiplied by 3!

Comment: Never mind got it

Comment: No... because swapping the position of two things that are the same doesn't change anything, so not every outcome you initially counted needs to be multiplied by $3!$.  $30\cdot \color{red}{1}\cdot \color{blue}{1}$ is the same as $30\cdot \color{blue}{1}\cdot \color{red}{1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Approaching via multiplication principle:

- pick which $x$-value receives the factor of $2$  (*three choices*)
- pick which $x$-value receives the factor of $3$ (*three choices*)
- pick which $x$-value receives the factor of $5$ (*three choices*)

As *any* $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ triple can be *uniquely* determined by a sequence of choices to the aforementioned steps, the total number of outcomes is the product of the number of choices, in this case $3\cdot 3\cdot 3=27$

---

For a more complicated question, look at how many positive integer tuples $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ exist where $x_1\cdot x_2\cdot x_3\cdot x_4 = 2^5\cdot 3^3$

Here, we again break up via multiplication principle

- Choose how to distribute the factors of $2$ among the $x$ values.  By analogy to stars and bars this is the number of solutions to $\begin{cases}a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=5\\0\leq a_i~~\forall i\end{cases}$ which is $\binom{5+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{8}{3}$
- Choose how to distribute the factors of $3$ among the $x$ values.  Similarly this will be $\binom{3+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{6}{3}$

There are then $\binom{8}{3}\cdot \binom{6}{3}$ different tuples satisfying the conditions

---

The problem can be made more complicated by allowing the integers to be negative as well.  To handle that, in addition to the other steps in multiplication principle, add the steps: choose whether $x_1$ is positive or negative, choose whether $x_2$ is positive or negative, $\dots$, choose whether $x_{n-1}$ is positive or negative.  Note that the final $x$ term *must* be positive in the case that the product of the previous terms is positive, or it must be negative if the product of the previous terms is negative.  For the $x_1\cdot x_2\cdot x_3\cdot x_4=2^5\cdot 3^3$ example, if the integers were allowed to be negative as well, this increases the count to a new total of $2^3\binom{8}{3}\binom{6}{3}$

Comment: @OsheenSachdev added more information for common complications to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward approach (but not the most elegant or most efficient) is to consider all divisors of $30$, namely:

$$ 1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30 \enspace. $$

Let $x_1$ range over those values.  For $x_1=1$, $x_2$ can take any value that is a divisor of $30$; then, $x_3$ is simply $30/x_2$.  This gives $8$ different solution.

For $x_1 = 2$, $x_2$ can be any value from $1,3,5,15$; then $x_3 = 15/x_2$.  This gives anothe $4$ solutions.  Continuing in this fashion, we reach $x_1 = 30$, for which $x_2 = x_3 = 1$.  All in all, we get $27$ solutions.

Comment: "The *simplest* approach"... simpler than multiplication principle and just saying its $3\times 3\times 3$?

Comment: Simpler conceptually.  I like your solution better.  Please, make it an answer so that it may be accepted.